# rake db:create gives undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rake, psql

Postgres 9.3, Ruby 2.1.0

`rake db:create` isn't making a test database. I already have a production database. I tried using RAILS_ENV=test rake db:create to force it but it returns "test database is not configured.

My `database.yml` ->

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: app_prod
  host: localhost

test: &test
  adapter: postgresql
  database: app_test
  host: localhost

cucumber:
  <<: *test

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: app_prod
  host: localhost
```

So it is configured. I also tried just using a console createdb app_test to create my test database but I receive the same error when I try to run rake db:test:prepare.

Anyone have any ideas?

**this is --trace on db:create:all**

```
** Invoke db:create:all (first_time)

** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)

** Execute db:load_config

** Execute db:create:all

rake aborted!
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:189:in `block in each_local_configuration'
```

**this is trace on db:test:prepare**

```
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)

** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)

** Execute db:load_config

** Execute db:test:prepare

** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)

** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)

** Invoke environment (first_time)

** Execute environment

** Invoke db:load_config

** Execute db:test:purge
rake aborted!
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `purge'
```

Comment: As a note, use the `{}` button to format code.

Comment: use `--trace` to find where things are going wrong

Comment: Thanks I tried that, didn't see anything I could use : (

Comment: Maybe you need to set the port explicitly, I remember I needed to do that some time ago

Comment: 99% sure that's not it, thanks though!

Comment: What do you get when you run this in console -> `ActiveRecord::Base.configurations`. You should get your database configurations.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.3/activerecord/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb, Line 189 is the one failing in your case which would mean that your database configurations are not loaded

Comment: I would suggest you test gem file if you have not added pg under test group

Comment: @Vimsha thanks a lot, there was some kind of strange character in my database.yml, if you submit your two comments as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this in console

```
ActiveRecord::Base.configurations
```

You should get your database configurations.

Line 3 in this method(Line 189 in [github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.3/activerecord/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb)) is failing in your case because configuration is nil

```
def each_local_configuration
    ActiveRecord::Base.configurations.each_value do |configuration|
      next unless configuration['database']

      if local_database?(configuration)
        yield configuration
      else
        $stderr.puts "This task only modifies local databases. #{configuration['database']} is on a remote host."
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: That was exactly it and it was nil due *I think* to an invisble character in my .yml file. Thanks Vimsha :D